# Display tag table header column disappear

Tags: jsp, displaytag

I have a display tag table.

```
        <display:table class="displayTable" id="ItemList"
            name="${sessionScope.List}" requestURI="listItem.action"
            pagesize="15" defaultsort="2" defaultorder="ascending" sort="list" >
            <display:column class="colID">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checked"
                    value="${ItemList.itemId}" />
            </display:column>
            <display:column class="colItemName" property="itemName"
                title="${titleItemName}" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" 
            />
            <display:column property="categoryName"
                title="${titleCategory}" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" />
        </display:table>
```

which will create like the below HTML.

```
<table id="itemList" class="displayTable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th class="sortable sorted order1">
<a href="lisItem.action?d-5522365-s=1&amp;d-5522365-p=1&amp;d-5522365-o=1">Item Name</a></th>
<th class="sortable">
<a href="listItem.action?d-5522365-s=2&amp;d-5522365-p=1&amp;d-5522365-o=2">Category</a></th>
<th></th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
....
```

My problem is when I add and return back to Listing, header (eg.Item Name, Category)of display tag table disappears.

And after I added a new item, there are added new item info mixed on 
 `<a href="lisItem.action?d-5522365-s=1&amp;d-5522365-p=1&amp;d-5522365-o=1">Item Name</a></th>` and becomes like this

`<a href="listItem.action?Item.ItemId=0&amp;Item.Name=Blah Blah &amp;Item.CategoryId=1&amp;d-5522365-s=1&amp;d-5522365-p=1&amp;d-5522365-o=1"></a></th>`

and then **Item Name** disappear from the link header.

Answer (score 0):

please note that display tag is going to call action 'listItem.action' after every event like sorting , exporting .

make sure that every time it redirects to the same page it should get 'sessionScope.List' .

kindly provide exact error or description of the error.